# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "services" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "services".* FROM "services"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, cron, whenever

I have some trouble using the whenever gem. I create a rake task which is working perfectly fine when I launch it myself BUT when I try to automate it with whenever I got the following message in my log:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "services" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "services".* FROM "services"
                                 ^
: SELECT "services".* FROM "services"
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:590:in `block in log'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in `log'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `exec_no_cache'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:585:in `execute_and_clear'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:103:in `exec_query'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:377:in `select_prepared'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:39:in `select_all'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:95:in `select_all'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:706:in `exec_queries'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:583:in `load'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:260:in `records'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:38:in `each'
/Users/Naekh/code/yoando/statuschecker/statuschecker/lib/tasks/fb_ping.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Naekh/code/yoando/statuschecker/statuschecker/lib/tasks/rake_them_all.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Is this a naming issue ? I check and double check but did I miss something?

my environment is development.

Here is my schedule.rb:

```
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
every 2.minutes do
  rake 'check:all', :environment => 'development'
end
```

and my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170922073721) do

  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "pings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "up"
    t.integer  "service_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["service_id"], name: "index_pings_on_service_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "services", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "web_api"
    t.string   "json_path"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "pings", "services"
end
```

here is my models:
- service.rb

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pings, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :web_api, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

- ping.rb

  class Ping < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :service
  end

Comment: Can you add your models @Doge?

Comment: I'd assume that the cron job created by whenever does not have access to the same set of gems (?altough it should fail normally, then?). Can you try to run the rake task with the same bash the cron job uses?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Just did, thanks

Comment: @ulferts I runned : /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/Naekh/code/yoando/statuschecker/statuschecker && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake check:all --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log' in my terminal and got the same error

Comment: Did you make sure migrations were run in your development environment?  
`bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` because your cron job is using development.  Also can you post the rake task?  Is it using same environment

Comment: @lacostenycoder for now I'm on the development environment

Comment: sorry i modified my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found where the problem was thanks to your comments.

Cron is sending this:

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/Naekh/code/yoando/statuschecker/statuschecker && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake check:all --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'
```

As you can see, he is sending it to the production environment, even if in my schedule:

```
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
every 2.minutes do
  rake 'check:all', :environment => 'development'
end
```

I'm telling him to send it to the development environment. I need now to find a way to force him to go in that environment as when i run:

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/Naekh/code/yoando/statuschecker/statuschecker && RAILS_ENV=environment bundle exec rake check:all --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'
```

it works

I updated cronjob environment with:

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```

and now it's working smoothly